Live Seismograph Plot with Grove 3-Axis Accelerometer and Seeed Studio ESP32-C3
I'm working on a hobby project to make a seismometer using a Grove 3-axis accelerometer along with a Seeed Studio ESP32-C3 to record accelerations. I am successfully getting the data to the serial port of my system and have set a delay of 50ms to obtain a 40Hz sample rate.
I'm using Python to read the data from the serial port and live plot it similar to a seismograph. However, the plot does not look like a real seismograph.
Here are my requirements:
The x-axis should be the UTC timestamp.
The y-axis should be the acceleration (Z-axis) value.
The plot must show data for the whole day, with each grid representing 30 seconds.
Below is the code I am currently using:
import serial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

ser = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)

# Initialize the data containers
max_len = 300  # Number of data points to display at once
ax_data = deque([0.0]*max_len, maxlen=max_len)
ay_data = deque([0.0]*max_len, maxlen=max_len)
az_data = deque([0.0]*max_len, maxlen=max_len)
time_data = deque([datetime.now()]*max_len, maxlen=max_len)

# Set up the plot
fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 8))

ax3.set_title('Z-Axis Acceleration')

ax3.set_ylim(-1,1)

ax3.grid(True,linewidth=0.5)

line3, = ax3.plot(time_data, az_data, label='Z-axis')

def update(frame):
    try:
        data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
        ax, ay, az = map(float, data.split(','))
        # Store the data in the deque
        az_data.append(az)
        time_data.append(datetime.now())
        # Center around zero by subtracting the mean
        az_array = np.array(az_data)
        az_centered = az_array - np.mean(az_array)

        # Update the plot data
        line3.set_data(time_data, az_centered)

        # Adjust the plot limits dynamically
        ax3.relim()
        ax3.autoscale_view()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    return line3,

# Set up animation with reduced interval (adjust as needed)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=20)  # Interval set to 20 milliseconds
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

